# The difference in work of gekko with (remote=false) and without this parameter

Tags: python, optimization, gekko

I am using GEKKO for fitting purposes.
During the exploration of GEKKO I have found that if I use:

```
model = GEKKO(remote=False)
```

instead of

```
model = GEKKO()
```

it is working much faster :)

But in this case I can't use IPOPT solver? I have provided a GEKKO with an option

```
model.options.SOLVER = 3
```

And then I have got the message during the solution:

```
solver            3  not supported
 using default solver: APOPT
 ----------------------------------------------
 Model Parameter Estimation with APOPT Solver
 ----------------------------------------------
```

And in the bottom of the log it's stated:

```
 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  IPOPT (v3.12)
 Solution time  :   0.736799999998766      sec
 Objective      :   0.148853103506686     
 Successful solution
 ---------------------------------------------------
```

So what solver is used in this mode?

P.S.
In case I use

```
model = GEKKO()
```

and for the same data I have another solution and a message about the used time:

```
---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  IPOPT (v3.12)
 Solution time  :    37.1334000000061      sec
 Objective      :   0.147929143743533     
 Successful solution
 ---------------------------------------------------
```

The solution I have got using `model = GEKKO()` is much better but it's time consuming.
So what is the difference between two cases and is there any information that can be used for better parameter tuning?

For example, I am ready to give APOPT the same time to find a solution but I don't get how to tune it.

P.P.S.
The function is nonconvex and I understand that there are a lot of local minima in the observable region so a large number of iterations are provided, e.g. 10000 iterations (I don't know if it's a large number or not - for my purpose it takes a lot of time).

Answer (score 0):

The local solver options are limited by licensing or size of the executable. On Linux / MacOS, including IPOPT for a local solve increases the library distribution size to 50 MB+. IPOPT is locally available on Windows because it only adds ~3 MB based on the way libraries are statically linked. Here is additional information from the [Readme.md file in the bin folder for Gekko](https://github.com/BYU-PRISM/GEKKO/blob/master/gekko/bin/README.md). The local executables are used when option `remote=False` when creating the Gekko model.

```py
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
```

Versions of the local executable include:

- Windows (32 or 64 bit): apm.exe
- Linux (64 bit): apm
- MacOS (64 bit): apm_mac
- Linux ARM (Raspberry Pi): apm_arm (temporarily removed until new version is available)

The incorrect reporting of the solver has a [GitHub Issue report](https://github.com/BYU-PRISM/GEKKO/issues/101) and will be fixed in a future version. If you need to use IPOPT, I recommend that you switch to the Windows version for local solution or else use the public server.

If you'd like to tune APOPT, here is additional information on the solver options in the [APMonitor documentation](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/OptionApmSolver) and from the [APOPT website](https://apopt.com/download.php).